# Initializing 2 dimensional array

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array

I need to initialize 2 dimensional array with m rows and n columns, but `m` and `n` might change. I found here example like this :

```
ARRAY[[NULL,NULL],[NULL,NULL]]
```

But it initializes array with 2 rows and 2 columns.

Comment: If you'd post the answer you found as answer and not in the question, I'd vote for it, because it's useful.

Comment: Yep, please answer your own post and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer:

```
array_fill(0,ARRAY[m,n])
```